# Merging two datasets using the last value of a string

Tags: r

I found the following code to pull off the last value in a string:

```
tail(strsplit("The quick brown fox",split = " ")[[1]],1)
```

which correctly returns the value of `"fox"`. I'm trying to apply this same principle to a text variable using the following code:

```
policy.data$LastName <- tail(strsplit(policy.data$Name,split = " ")[[1]],1)
```

but this code gives me the following error:

> Error in strsplit(policy.data$Name, split = " ") : non-character argument*

I do not understand why the code works when the string is specified but not with a text variable. I have a data set that has a full first and last name (`"Jane Doe"`) and a data set that has the first initial and last name (`"J Doe"`).  What I am really trying to do is merge the two datasets using last name (`"Doe"`) so if there is a way to do this without creating a separate variable called "LastName" in each dataset, I would be very interested in that solution as well.

Comment: Please post a sample dataset, by dput or some other ways, just for better understanding of the issue and better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Convert   policy.data$LastName to character using as.character():

```
   policy <- data.frame(LastName=c("The quick brown fox"))
   policy
    policy$LastName # it's considered as factor not character
  # so convert to character

  as.character(policy$LastName)
  tail(strsplit(as.character(policy$LastName),split = " ")[[1]],1)
```

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/UEMU78022)

output:

```
        LastName
   1 The quick brown fox
  [1] The quick brown fox
  Levels: The quick brown fox
  [1] "The quick brown fox"
  [1] "fox"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strsplit()` function requires the first argument to be a vector (of characters). The `policy.data$Name` is most likely a factor. You can check using the `str()` function.

Try

```
policy.data$LastName <- tail(strsplit(as.vector(policy.data$Name),split = " ")[[1]],1)
```